# fancybox implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am a novice with jquery and am having great trouble implementing fancy box. I've followed all of the instructions according to the user guide and have scoured the internet for many examples. I'm tying it into code-igniter so not sure if that is making a difference.

I am trying to just use it for a simple - click a link and show a text box with content and hyperlinks.

I have all of the files in a folder called 'fancybox' in my applications folder.

Here is my header:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.0" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.3" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.6" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.0"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.3"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.3"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.6"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox();
            content:kljsadlkfajsdlfkjasdflkjads;
        });
    </script>
```

and here is the html view:

```
        <div class="resources">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="#">test</a>
        </div>
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Is 'content' a property/parameter of fancybox()?

Comment: You forgot to quote the content's value as well.

Comment: I am actually not sure tbh. That's why I'm asking. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want fancybox to automatically find the element to show, put the id of that element in the `href` attribute.

```
<a href="#box1" class="fancybox">Show box 1</a>
<div style="display:none"><div id="box1">I am in fancybox!</div></div>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

If you want to manually show a fancybox dialog, just call it:

```
$("#box1").fancybox();
```

Comment: that makes wonderful sense, but I'm still not getting anything. I'm thinking I'm ordering something wrong with my script tags and or css tags. All of my path's seem to be correct. I'm also not confident that I"m including the right js files. Do you have a header example I could see or a suggestion based upon what I posted above? thanks

Comment: I would suggest you use a debugging tool (Developer Tools in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox) and look for any runtime errors. Also look for the existence of `$.fn.fancybox` and `$.fancybox`. You can do this by typing `$.fanc` in the console and see if it suggests `$.fancybox`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in how you are calling fancybox. You've got the syntax wrong.

You need to pass your options as an object.

e.g

```
// Override content
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    content: "kljsadlkfajsdlfkjasdflkjads"
});
```

Further examples are shown in the [docs](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)